# Calculating the area and position of dynamically formed polygons

Tags: objective-c, math, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, polygon

Hi stackoverflow community,

This is a continuation of a question I asked 6 months regarding [calculating the area and position of dynamically formed rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228649/calculating-the-area-and-position-of-dynamically-formed-rectangles). The solution provided for that worked a treat but now I want to take this a step further.

Some background - I'm working on a puzzle game using Cocos2D/Box2D were the player draws lines on the screen. Depending on were the player draws, I want to then work out the area and position of polygons that appear as a result of the drawn lines.

In the following image, the black border represents a playing area, this will always be the same shape. The grey lines are player drawn and will always be straight. The green square is an obstacle. The obstacle objects will be convex shapes. The formed polygons (3 in this case) are the blue areas and are the shapes I'm trying to get the coordinates and area for.

[image: image showing play area for polygon game]

I think I'll be fine with working out the area of a polygon using determinants but before that, I need to work out the coordinates of the blue polygons and I'm not sure how to do this.

I've got the lines (x,y) coordinates for both ends, the coordinates for the obstacle and the corner coordinates for the black border. Using those, is it possible to work out the coordinates of the blue polygons or am I approaching this the wrong way?

UPDATE - response to duffymo

Thanks for your answer. To explain further, each object mentioned is defined and encapsulated in a class i.e. I've got a Line/Obstacle/PlayingArea object. My polygon object is encapsulated in a 'Rectangle' object. Each one of these objects has it's own properties associated with it such as its coordinates/area/ID/state etc...

In order to keep track of all the objects, I've got an over-seeing singleton object which holds all of the Line objects / Obstacle objects etc in their own respective array. This way, I can loop through say all Lines and know were each one has been drawn by the player.

The game is a bit like [classic JezzBall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VD6GQJxHh7E) so I need to be able to create these polygon shapes when a user draws a line because the polygon shape will be used as my way of detecting if that particular area contains a ball. If not the area needs to be filled.

Comment: Do you know which edge of the black border a grey endpoint intersects?

Comment: Hi Beta, yes I could get that information. Not sure if this throws a spanner in the works but lines will not always be connected to the black border. They may be connected to another line for example: http://postimg.org/image/6cy2za8q3/

Comment: And do you want the list of vertices to include interior points? That is, before any grey lines are drawn, should the list for the blue region include the vertices of the green rectangle? If there is a free-floating grey line embedded in the blue region, should those two endpoints be on the list?

Comment: If the green rectangle is part of or completes the blue region then its vertices should be included in the blue regions path. If there is a free-floating grey line embedded in the blue region then yes, it's endpoints should be included. Maybe another image will help. In the image linked, the same coloured stars denote each blue region I'm after. In essence, I should be left with the vertices for 5 separate blue regions/polygons. http://s4.postimg.org/yra4j0jfh/rectangle_problem_areas.png

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the nodes and edges for your polygons, I'd recommend that you calculate the centroids, perimeters, and areas using [contour integration](http://shuisman.com/?p=359)  You can express the centroids and areas as contour integrals using Green's theorem.

You can use [Gaussian quadrature](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianQuadrature.html) to do piecewise integration along each edge.

It'll be fast and accurate; it'll work on polygons of arbitrary complexity.

UPDATE: Objective-C is an object-oriented language.  I don't know it myself, but I believe it's based on ideas from C and C++.  Since that's the case, I'd recommend that you start writing more in terms of objects.  Arrays of coordinates?  They need to encapsulated together.  I'd suggest a Point abstraction that encapsulates a point (id, x, y) together.  Make a Grid that has a List of Points.

It sounds like users supply the relationship between Points to form Polygons.  That's not clear from your description, so it's not a surprise that you're having trouble implementing it.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but even though I've got the coordinates for the lines/obstacle/playing area, these coordinates aren't arranged in a way which gives me the nodes/edges of the 3 polygons. They're simply stored in 3 separate arrays (line array/obstacle array/playingArea array) with no awareness of the other objects coordinates. I'm struggling to work out how to establish the coordinates of the dynamically formed polygons depending on were the player draws a line.